# Приложение через дефис: "создание компании лидера туристической сферы"

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, в случае "создание компании лидера туристической сферы", как пишется компании лидера (через дефис или нет)?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что нужно тире: «создание компании — лидера туристической сферы». Если бы у слова *лидера* не было зависимых слов, тогда да — «компании–лидера».

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25602/discussion-between---and-nick-volynkin).

Comment: я пришел в чат, а вас там нет...

Comment: И общению в чате пришлось учиться))).

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае нужно тире, а не дефис. Т.к. это распространенное приложение.

"Создание компании — лидера туристической сферы"

Answer (score 0):

Я бы отредактировал предложение, выкинув слово "компании". "Создание лидера туристической индустрии!" Понятно, что речь идет о компании, а не о чем-то еще. Вообще, если с предложением возникают сложности, золотое правило - прежде всего подумать, а не стоит ли его переформулировать или сократить?

Comment: Не надо ничего без нужды редактировать. Вас просят дать ответ на конкретный вопрос, касательно правописания, а не стилистики. А постоянные намеки, что автор ей не владеет - "не есть гуд", даже для бывшего редактора.

Comment: Критика полезна авторам. Не все люди на этом форуме инфантильны. Многие из них спокойно воспринимают критику, без истерик.. Поэтому остаюсь при своем мнении. :)

Comment: Если критика полезна, почему вы так нервно реагируете на неё? ))) Ладно, спорить с Вами на отвлеченные темы я больше не буду. Я Вас услышал, мнение свое высказал. А вот пол сути обещаю взять на контроль все Ваши ответы. Мне это совсем не сложно. )))

Comment: ***обещаю взять на контроль все Ваши ответы И тут Бегемотик стал угрожать.. Кстати, спасибо за этот коммент. Я его передам админу ресурса.